# Combinar dos HashMap con claves duplicadas

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

tengo que hacer un `Map` el cuál tiene las mismas claves que otros dos Maps, y los valores asociados a estas son la media aritmética de los valores de las claves de los otros dos. Ej:

```
Map<String, Double> map1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> map2 = new HashMap<>();
Map<String, Double> map3 = new HashMap<>();

map1.put("clave1", 10.0);
map1.put("clave2", 4.0);
map2.put("clave1", 10.0);
map2.put("clave2", 6.0);
```

Las claves que hay en `map1` y `map2` son las mismas, y lo que busco es que `map3` contenga `("clave1", 10.0),("clave2",5.0)`. Me interesaría resolverlo con Java 8 y trabajando con streams si es posible, he intentado usar el método `merge` pero sobreescribe los valores. Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes primero copiar uno de los Map a map3:

```
map3= new HashMap(map1);
```

Y luego hacer el merge sobre éste:

```
map2.forEach((key, value) -> map3.merge(key, value, (v1, v2) -> (v1+v2)/2);
```

Puedes probarlo [aquí](https://tio.run/##fY7NTsMwEITP8VOsenIgNY2LuBR6AolLT30Ck5rUaRJb/kMV6rOHdUpRVSi@eLXfzOw0IoqpNrJvNrthUJ3R1kODSxa8atnNgpjw1qoKqlY4Byuhevgkp6XzwuMXtdpAlxBde6v6mjEGwtYuR232Ktx2JczjERXwrNEsl2gwJTxBLz/gJFnSfPGvgf9pICRLYcwETydYNMpyUkA5Y7NELxBHdP9D@HUTvzA9jIRkV6rNf1VLh9EB32@MfNf2RVRbSndyX0AUbZA5TI8BrJO2lmekABpLnPkowfkWxzuen4Wu987LjungmcFKvu3T2TkqDuQwDF8).

Nota: Ya que la propia interfaz Map ya incluye el método forEach, no he usado un Stream, pero añadirlo sólo para cumplir las restricciones me parece innecesario en este caso (algo como `map2.stream().forEach(). ... ;`)